# R: store plots to a list then weave in knitr document

Tags: r, knitr

I want a custom function to generate a few plots for me then output them woven into the knitr document.

Generating the plots and adding them to a list just gives me a vector not a plot.

Any clues?

````
   tesing
   =======================

   ```{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
   mytest <- function(myresponse, myterms, mydata) {
     # do clever stuff...
     # then:
     plot1 <- barplot(ppr$pain_protocol1, name=ppr$category,las=2)
     plot2 <- barplot(ppr_pa$extra_pp, name=ppr_pa$adult_anaesthetist,las=2)
     list(plot1 = plot1, plot2 = plot2)
   }

   terms <- c(' age', 'log_age', 'age2', 'inv_age', 'op_time', 'log_op_time',
       'op_time2', 'gender', 'category', 'thimble')
   response <- 'pain_protocol1'
   results <- mytest(response, terms, d4)

   ```
````

Then neither of these two work:

````
  This is plot 1:

  ```{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot_build(results[["plot1"]])
  ```

  This is plot 2:

  ```{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
  results[["plot2"]]
  ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `barplot` function in R is a "base graphics" function that draws when you call it. You can't save the plot like that and expect to replay it by printing - I suspect you are used to `ggplot` and grid graphics that **do** work like that.

One fix might be to use `ggplot` graphics to do the plot. Your code example isn't reproducible so I'll stop here because I can't tell what you want exactly.

Here's a solution for base graphics using `recordPlot`. You just have to hide the plots when you create them by using a chunk option, otherwise they appear twice. Note this is a reproducible example - put this in `foo.Rmd`, run `knit2html("foo.Rmd")`, view `foo.html` in your browser:

````
tesing
=======================

```{r echo=FALSE,results='asis'}
mytest <- function() {
 set.seed(310366)
  mydata = data.frame(x=runif(10),y1=runif(10),y2=runif(10))
  plot(mydata$x, mydata$y1)
  plot1 = recordPlot()
  plot(mydata$x, mydata$y2)
  plot2 = recordPlot()
  list(plot1 = plot1, plot2 = plot2)
}
```

And now create the plots but don't show...

```{r figures,fig.show="hide"}
plots = mytest()
```

Now show the first

```{r plot1here}
plots[[1]]
```

and then another

```{r plot2here}
plots[[2]]
```
````

Comment: promising! thanks - but now seem to have a path issue `  This is plot 1:

  ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-2](figure/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png) 

  This is plot 2:

  ![plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-3](figure/unnamed-chunk-3-1.png) `

Comment: Is that "path issue" when you run my code or yours? Are you looking at the raw markdown output rather than the HTML? You've not specified your knitr process - obviously you are using markdown as source and I've knitted it to HTML.

Comment: Thanks for help so far. These messages are in the final html after I modified my code to match yours. I am sure it's a simple configuration setting. I'll investigate further and hopefully accept your answer when I get it working.

Comment: I found the glitch - it turns out that the `plots[[2]]` line breaks if prefixed with 4 or more spaces! so no indenting!